# Can we use SignalR in .NET Rest API project?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I have minimal API projects in .NET core 7. The frontend project is separate and created in Vue JS. I need to use SignalR for the notification module, but I can't figure out if this is really possible?
in.NET, all I have is REST APIs for my project, I created an API for SingleR, and it's being called from Vue JS, but the message is not being delivered to the client. Connect ID is being generated. Do I need to create some background services etc. in my understanding, once REST API is being called, it can't be connected forever for WebSocket purpose.

Comment: Think about your overall architecture. What are you trying to build? What are the pieces that you need to build that thing. Draw an architectural diagram with something like this https://excalidraw.com/ and show what the moving parts of the system are. 

The browser, the server, where does signalr run, how does data flow, what requests are made etc.